# How to copy a defined node and put it somewhere we want?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}                         
\usetikzlibrary{calc}                   
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}      
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill,minimum size=5mm] (head) {};
\node[rounded corners=2pt,minimum height=1.3cm,minimum width=0.4cm,fill,below = 1pt of head] (body) {};
\draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(2pt,-1pt)}]body.north east) --++(-90:6mm);
\draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(-2pt,-1pt)}]body.north west)--++(-90:6mm);
\draw[thick,white,-round cap] (body.south) --++(90:5.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above code, I define a node `(A)` with a human shape. But I am wondering whether I can obtain the `pic` below via copying, moving and scaling the defined node `(A)`?
(The pic below is obtained by Word.)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would define a `\newcommand` with an optional argument for the scaling.

The command is `\human[#1]{#2}{3}`, where

- `#1` is the optional argument. If you don't define it (not writing the `[]`), then the scale is 1.
- `#2` is the node's name. I used `A, B, C`.
- `#3` is the position. It's done as any other node, like `(0,0)` or `(5,0)`.

About the tikz library: you can write one and add all the options there. Also, you should switch to `arrows.meta` (redefining the shape with the new line caps).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % I added this because it was complaining about fonts
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}  

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}      

\newcommand{\human}[3][1]{
\node[scale=#1] (#2) at (#3) {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill,minimum size=5mm] (head) {};
\node[rounded corners=2pt,minimum height=1.3cm,minimum width=0.4cm,fill,below = 1pt of head] (body) {};
\draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(2pt,-1pt)}]body.north east) --++(-90:6mm);
\draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(-2pt,-1pt)}]body.north west)--++(-90:6mm);
\draw[thick,white,-round cap] (body.south) --++(90:5.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]

\human{A}{0,0} % scaling not defined
\human[2]{B}{3,-2} % double the size, double the fun!
\human[.5]{C}{3,2} % meh, a bit smaller.

\draw (A.east) -- (B.west);
\draw (A.east) -- (C.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Time for a `pic`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

\tikzset{
 man/.pic={
           \begin{scope}[scale=#1,every node/.style={scale=0.8*#1}]
              \node[circle,fill,minimum size=5mm] (head) {};
               \node[rounded corners=2pt,minimum height=1.3cm,minimum width=0.4cm,fill,
                   below = 1pt of head] (body) {};
                \draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(2pt,-1pt)}]body.north east)
                   --++(-90:6mm);
                \draw[line width=1mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(-2pt,-1pt)}]body.north
                   west)--++(-90:6mm);
                \draw[thick,white,-round cap] (body.south) --++(90:5.5mm);
            \end{scope}
        }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (a) at (0,0) {man={1.3}};
\pic[above right = 2cm and 2cm of abody] (b) {man={.9}};
\pic[below right = 1cm and 2cm of abody] (c) {man={.9}};
\draw[-latex,shorten >=1em] ([xshift=3em]abody.west) -- (bbody);
\draw[-latex,shorten >=1em] ([xshift=3em]abody.west) -- (cbody);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]